# How to disable Notification for Terminal app?

Tags: macos, terminal, notifications

When i am starting a new server from the Terminal app, and i have the window not active, the Dock icon "jumps" up and down, also called "notifies me".

I don't want this behaviour, i want a quiet Terminal. I know when i am starting and stopping sth.

> How can i do that?

**I've already disabled the audio and visual bell, but still: Jumping.**

*System version: Mavericks.*

Comment: I don't think it is possible. I am pretty sure this is something handled by the system and is out of the users hands.

Comment: Use iTerm2? Not the best answer, hence it's a comment instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whilst it's not ideal, if it's that bad you could disable the app bounce notification completely for all apps:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE && killall -HUP Dock
```

<sup>To revert, replace `TRUE` with `FALSE`.</sup>

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score 8):

I am running the Terminal version 2.9.1 and macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and I could just do this in the preference setting of the Terminal App:

Terminal > Preferences > Profiles tab > Advanced tab > Uncheck everything under the Bell section

Unchecking 'Bounce app icon when in background' option would prevent jumping of the terminal icon.

[image: Here's a screenshot after unchecking the notification options.]

Comment: That works at least since El Capitan and probably before that

Comment: Terminal > Preferences > Profiles tab > Advanced tab > Uncheck everything under the Bell section: worked for me on Big Surveillance M1

Answer (score 2):

Running your commands in gnu screen can solve your problem.

Steps to replicate bad behavior:

1. `$ sleep 5; tout bel`
2. Command-Tab away from Terminal
3. Wait

Observed behavior: Terminal icon gets badge and bounces

Desired behavior: No badge or bounce

Solution:

1. `$ screen`
2. Control+A, c # create a new screen window
3. `$ sleep 5; tput bel`
4. Control+A, Control+A # switch to screen 0
5. Command-Tab away from Terminal

New observed behavior: No badge or bounce

Note that you'll still get badge + bounce if the screen window is the active one. I'm sure you can refine this further.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just issuing one long-running command that occasionally pops a bell, you could run the command with the output piped to less. This seems to have done the trick for me:

```
annoyingcmd | less -R
```

(The -R flag allows for colors to be displayed)